# 502 error django + nginx + gunicorn - connect() recv()

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I've set up a Digital Ocean one-click app (django + nginx + gunicorn are installed and setup https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-django-one-click-install-image). Defaults worked for me, but after I tried to apply code changes via `service gunicorn restart` I received a 502 error with the following nginx error log line:

```
 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 178.136.215.70, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1",upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/"..
```

I have looked into similar issues and found that often it's caused by a mistake in ALLOWED_HOSTS, everything is right there, but I also tried to replace `'ip'` or `'www.address.com'` with single `'*'`  and got a different error:

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 178.136.215.70, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "192.241.176.184"
```

EDIT: ok, now it's easier, gunicorn error log is telling us that there is an import error with rest_framework, But it's installed and it's present in Installed app (and spelled right), I'v checked like thousand times so what's really wrong with all that?

```
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/django/django_project/blog/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from rest_framework import serializers
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named rest_framework
```

(the only issue for now)EDIT2: I have reinstalled the app folder, checked again everything. Now it's telling that `ImportError: No module named django_ajax`. Python 2.7 , Django 1.8, Gunicorn 19.4.5 (https://github.com/yceruto/django-ajax) despite everything seems to be correct [image]

EDIT: Résponse of pip freeze:

```
    Django==1.8
django-filter==1.0.1
-e git://github.com/yceruto/django-ajax@9c122e68f8e7ca92333a1533fa464ee6da0f65c5#egg=djangoajax
djangorestframework==3.5.3
gunicorn==19.6.0
Markdown==2.6.7
netifaces==0.10.5
pkg-resources==0.0.0
psycopg2==2.6.2
```

Comment: Did you install the django-ajax package?

Comment: @Oliver Why would I ask otherwise? Sure, I did and checked several times

Comment: Did you install the right one? There seems to be `django-ajax` and `djangoajax`.

Comment: @Oliver the right one. I supposed maybe it could be related to using python 3.5 in local environment compared to 2.7 on virtual machine, because in order to deploy updates  I only copy only files inside app folder on server?

Comment: @Oliver or some other kind of versions incompatibility or wrong paths ??

Comment: Ahhh, you need to install the libraries in the VM by running pip (or pip2.7) install, just copying the app folder files is not sufficient.

Comment: @Oliver No, no :)  I obviously installed every library in the VM also, checked the presence of files and despite the fact of presence and installation it responses with such kind or error

Comment: I installed the package django-ajax in my venv, then it was able to import django_ajax

Could you plaese do pip freeze with the virtualenv activated to see if this is already installed.

Comment: @RahulReddyVemireddy seems to be: -e git://github.com/yceruto/django-ajax@9c122e68f8e7ca92333a1533fa464ee6da0f65c5#egg=djangoajax

Comment: @RahulReddyVemireddy if I try installing via pip again, it responses with 'requirement already satisfied ' and paths where packages are located

Comment: Can you share the response of "pip freeze". That would help us understand, if the django-ajax library is installed in the venv or on the machine itself

Comment: @ sure, I am updating the question with response

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting a github link for django-ajax. 

My pip freeze comes up like this.

Django==1.10.5
django-ajax==0.2.0

can you uninstall that and do pip install django-ajax

Comment: @RahulReddyVemireddy after I uninstalled django-ajax, and used pip freeze, github link was still there.  I installed again, and django-ajax==0.2.0  appeared . So I restarted gunicorn service, but it crashed with previous  error" No module named rest_framework". But.. I checked freeze again and it's there : djangorestframework==3.5.3

Comment: @RahulReddyVemireddy tried to uninstall and install djangorestframework again, but got the same result

Comment: Is gunicorn config using the python from the venv or is it using the python from the os? I mean, are you pointing to the venv python... It doesn't look like that from the error messages. I might be wrong. 

Check this [tutorial](http://tutos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/ndg.html#gunicorn-and-daemonizing-it)

Comment: @RahulReddyVemireddy in gunicorn. conf ' --pythonpath=django_project \ ' so it must use venv python + this is pre-installed configuration so theoretically there shall be no mistakes

Comment: Makes sense. Can you search which Python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132441/discussion-between-vinand-and-rahul-reddy-vemireddy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do Sudo, the package is installed for the root user and it installed globally. Check this [link](https://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/) to understand how sudo pip works. Now that your package is installed globally, it is working.

I still have doubts about which Python is it using. In the error messages, it was trying to access packages under global dist-packages directory. Not from the virtual environment. So, your gunicorn send to be linked to the Python installed globally not the virtual environment one.

Ideally, the errors occurred should point to the dist-packages under the `/path/to/virtual_env/virtual_env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, as this is the python & the library environment that want to use. That seems to be the issue.

If this is the case, can you do the following

```
DJANGODIR=/path/to/django-project/ 
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django-project.settings
```

## Activate the virtual environment

```
cd $DJANGODIR
source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH
```

I think this should solve everything... Please try it out and lemme know if I missed out something

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, whether it shall be considered as answer, because I don't understand why exactly it works this way. If someone explains properly I'll mark one's answer as right one . So, this line worked for me

```
  sudo -H pip install djangorestframework
```

Despite packages were reported to be installed they were not.And despite they were visible after `pip freeze`. So I don't know real reason why just `pip install` didn't work but seemed to work instead(?), although all permissions are correct, and I tried from both root and other username with same privileges.